# Save bitmap image to specific location of gallery android 10

Tags: android, image, save, android-10.0

I am using this code:

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bitmap, "title" , "description");
```

and it is working well.

**Problems:**

1. It is creating a folder called **"Pictures"** in gallery automatically. But I want different name, for example my app's name.
2. insertImage() function of MediaStore is ***depreciated*** in android 10:

> public static String insertImage (ContentResolver cr,
> String imagePath,
> String name,
> String description)

> This method was deprecated in API level 29.
> inserting of images should be performed using MediaColumns#IS_PENDING, which offers richer control over lifecycle.

I have read the documentation and don't actually understand IS_PENDING and how to use it.

Comment: You do not want to save in the gallery but in the media store looking at your code.

Comment: You can only create your apps folder as subdirectory of one of the well know Documents, Download, DCIM, Pictures ... directories under Android 10.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try this code :-

```
private void saveImage(Bitmap bitmap, @NonNull String name) throws IOException {
    boolean saved;
    OutputStream fos;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        ContentResolver resolver = mContext.getContentResolver();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, name);
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/png");
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, "DCIM/" + IMAGES_FOLDER_NAME);
        Uri imageUri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
        fos = resolver.openOutputStream(imageUri);
    } else {
        String imagesDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).toString() + File.separator + IMAGES_FOLDER_NAME;

        File file = new File(imagesDir);

        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdir();
        }

        File image = new File(imagesDir, name + ".png");
        fos = new FileOutputStream(image);

    }

    saved = bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
}
```

Comment: You have not used IS_PENDING twice for Android 10. OP asked for that.

Comment: @blackapps  how to prevent multiple insertions of same images, when this function is called twice for the same bitmap

Comment: @mad_lad One can save the same bitmap a hundred times. Nobody will be checking if a bitmap is the same as used yesterday or so.

Comment: @blackapps this is my issue, whenever the user clicks the save image button in my app the above function is called. if the user clicks again on the save the image button, then the same image will be saved twice. How to prevent this issue.

Comment: Disable the button.

Comment: @blackapps disable the button is a nice idea. But the button has to be present, in this case. I have done another quick fix, here file names are unique. So, firstly get the name of the file to be saved. Then list the files in the folder to be saved and check if contains the given file name. If not, saved it. Do you have any other suggestions

Comment: What does it matter that an existing file with that name is overwritten again with the same bitmap? I see no problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233603/discussion-between-mad-lad-and-blackapps).

Comment: how we can get the path of saved bitmap image ?

Comment: @Arjunsaini is this method required `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission?

Comment: Yes you need to runtime permission for Above or equal to Marshmallow

Comment: After hours of searching , I finally managed to save an image. Thank you!!