# Unable to download Image through url into my phone in android 10

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I m trying to download image into phone storage through its url using glide its working fine in android 9 or below buts its not working in case of android 10,

Here is my adapter code  where i added download funtion, can some One help with the code

public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder> {

```
Context context;
 ArrayList<Model> modelArrayList;

public Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<Model> modelArrayList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.modelArrayList = modelArrayList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent,false);

    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    String url = modelArrayList.get(position).getUrl();
      holder.setImage(url);
      holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {
              Intent sharing = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_SEND);
              sharing.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
              sharing.setType("text/plain");
              String subject = "Hey Man just look at this coll meme click the link " +url;
              sharing.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,subject);
              context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharing,"Shring using"));
          }
      });

      holder.buttonDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override


          public void onClick(View view) {

                  
                    downloadImage(url);
          }
      });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return modelArrayList.size();
}

public class  ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    ImageView imageView;
    Button button,buttonDownload;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.button);
        buttonDownload = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_download);
    }

    void setImage(String link){
        Glide.with(context).load(link).into(imageView);
    }
}

     void downloadImage(String imageURL){

     String dirPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "memebook" + "/";
     final File dir = new File(dirPath);
     final String fileName = imageURL.substring(imageURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
     Glide.with(context)
                 .load(imageURL)
                 .into(new CustomTarget<Drawable>() {
                     @Override
                     public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Drawable resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Drawable> transition) {

                         Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)resource).getBitmap();
                         Toast.makeText(context, "Saving Image...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         saveImage(bitmap, dir, fileName);
                     }

                     @Override
                     public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {

                     }

                     @Override
                     public void onLoadFailed(@Nullable Drawable errorDrawable) {
                         super.onLoadFailed(errorDrawable);

                         Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to Download Image! Please try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     }
                 });

     }


private void saveImage(Bitmap image, File storageDir, String imageFileName) {

    boolean successDirCreated = false;
    if (!storageDir.exists()) {
        successDirCreated = storageDir.mkdir();
    }

    successDirCreated = true;
    if (successDirCreated) {
        File imageFile = new File(storageDir, imageFileName);
        String savedImagePath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
        try {
            OutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut);
            fOut.close();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Image Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Error while saving image!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }else{
        Toast.makeText(context, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `successDirCreated = true;` ????? Why are you doing that? Ik mkdir fails you should stop.

Comment: I think you can download the file just fine. Only saving a bitmap is not successfull. Please elaborate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68225788/how-to-download-a-image-from-url-in-recylerview i follwed this solution ,

Comment: Please dont post links but react to my comments to the point. You did not react at all.